# How to replace only the isolated variable x

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I want to replace the variable `x` in the result, not `x` in unrelated `x[i]`.

```
ω[n_] := Product[x - x[i - 1], {i, 1, n}]

D[ω[3], x] /. x -> x[k]
```

In the code above, I want to get a result like `(x[k] - x[0])*(x[k]  - x[1]) + (x[k]  - x[2])*(x[k]  - x[1]) +  (x[k]  - x[0])*(x[k]  - x[2])`. how can I solve this problem skillfully?

Comment: Why not just use `x[k]` in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Replace` with the option `Heads -> False`:

```
Replace[D[ω[3], x], x -> x[k], All, Heads -> False]
```

> ```
>  (-x[0] + x[k]) (-x[1] + x[k]) + (-x[0] + x[k]) (-x[2] + x[k]) + 
>   (-x[1] + x[k]) (-x[2] + x[k])
> ```

Alternatively, you can use `ReplaceAll` with the replacement rule `{p_x :> p, x -> x[k]}`:

```
D[ω[3], x] /. { p_x :> p, x -> x[k]}
```

> ```
>  (-x[0] + x[k]) (-x[1] + x[k]) + (-x[0] + x[k]) (-x[2] + x[k]) + 
>   (-x[1] + x[k]) (-x[2] + x[k])
> ```